# JPA @Convert issue with timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to encrypt some data stored in a MySQL database using the JPA `@Convert` options with an AES algorithm. In general, is working fine with all fields, but I am having issues with one of them that is a Timestamp. My version of Hibernate is 4.3.8.Final.

As it is my first time with converters, I am following this [GiT example](https://github.com/damienbeaufils/spring-data-jpa-encryption-example). For this test, the AES encryption **is disabled**, I will enable it later and is the reason which I want to convert some fields to String. Therefore the issue must be in the converter.

The entity stores a user with several typical information (name, lastname,...) and a birthdate that is stored as a Timestamp. Also, as I want to perform some search by `birthdate`, I remove all hours, seconds and milliseconds for birthdate in the entity in the setter.

```
public class User {
  @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
  @Convert(converter = StringCryptoConverter.class)
  private String firstname;

  ....

  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Convert(converter = TimestampCryptoConverter.class)
  private Timestamp birthdate;

  public void setBirthdate(Timestamp birthdate) {
    // Remove time from birthdate. Is useless and can cause troubles when
    // using in SQL queries.
    if (birthdate != null) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(birthdate.getTime());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // set hour to midnight
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // set minute in hour
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set second in minute
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // set millis in second
        this.birthdate = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    } else {
        this.birthdate = null;
    }
  }

....
}
```

The TimestampCryptoConverter.class has few methods that are very simple. In general the scope is to convert the Timestamp to string to apply later an AES algorithm, I take the time of the timestamp as a long with `getTime()`, and convert them to String:

```
@Override
protected Timestamp stringToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    try {
        return (dbData == null || dbData.isEmpty()) ? null : new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(dbData));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        Logger.errorMessage("Invalid long value in database.");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected String entityAttributeToString(Timestamp attribute) {
    return attribute == null ? null : attribute.getTime() + "";
}
```

This is a very simple code. And I can store the entity into the database correctly, and retrieve it from database correctly, for example, if I get the user by ID. Therefore, the converter must be correct.

The stored data into MySQL is something like:

```
# id, birthdate, firstname, ...
'1', '1525384800000', 'TEST', ...
```

If I search the user by any field, I retrieve the entity with all data correctly converted. The issue appears when I want to perform a search from the birthdate. For example, in my DAO, I have a method is:

```
public List<User> get(String email, Timestamp birthdate) {
    // Get the criteria builder instance from entity manager
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getEntityClass());
    // Tell to criteria query which tables/entities you want to fetch
    Root<User> typesRoot = criteriaQuery.from(getEntityClass());

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(typesRoot.get("email"), email));

    if (birthdate != null) {
        // Remove hours and seconds.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(birthdate.getTime());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // set hour to midnight
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // set minute in hour
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set second in minute
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // set millis in second
        birthdate = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(typesRoot.<Timestamp> get("birthdate"), birthdate));
    }

    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));

    return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

As you can see, I also remove the hours, seconds and milliseconds from the search query to match the value on the database.

If I call this method with only the email `get('test@email.com', null)`, it works fine, as before the user is retrieved and the birthdate is correct in the user.

But if I call this method with the birthdate `get('test@email.com', 2018-05-04 12:09:05.862)` then the result obtained is `null`. In some unitary tests, the timestamp used in the call is exactly the same parameter used for the creation of the user, and therefore must match the value on the database. For example, I have this unitary tests:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "storeUser" })
@Rollback(value = false)
@Transactional(value = TxType.NEVER)
public void searchByMailUser() {
    Assert.assertEquals(userDao.getRowCount(), 1);
    List<User> dbUsers = userDao.get(EMAIL, null);
    Assert.assertTrue(!dbUsers.isEmpty());

    User dbUser = dbUsers.iterator().next();
    Assert.assertEquals(dbUser.getFirstname(), FIRSTNAME);
    Assert.assertEquals(dbUser.getEmail(), EMAIL);
    ....        

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(BIRTHDATE.getTime());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // set hour to midnight
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // set minute in hour
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set second in minute
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // set millis in second
    Timestamp birthdate = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
    Assert.assertEquals(dbUser.getBirthdate(), birthdate);
}
```

That is executed fine, and the last assert tell me that the birthdate is stored and retrieved correctly. But in this test:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "storeUser" })
public void searchByMailAndBirthdateUser() {
    Assert.assertEquals(userDao.getRowCount(), 1);
    Assert.assertTrue(!userDao.get(EMAIL, BIRTHDATE).isEmpty());
}
```

This test is failed due to no users are found, but passed if changed to:

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "storeUser" })
public void searchByMailAndBirthdateUser() {
    Assert.assertEquals(userDao.getRowCount(), 1);
    Assert.assertTrue(!userDao.get(EMAIL, null).isEmpty());
}
```

BUT, if I disable the converter, both tests are passed.

If the birthdate is correctly retrieved from the database. Why I am having a `null` value when using birthdate as a criteria?

**EDIT**

Seems that the method `protected String entityAttributeToString(Timestamp attribute);` is not used when calling `get('test@email.com', 2018-05-04 12:09:05.862)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort, I have changed the version of Hibernate to `5.2.17.Final` and the Timestamps are handled correctly with the `@Convert` annotation. That means that is really an Hibernate bug with version `4.X` and this feature is better implemented in Hibernate `5.X`

Answer (score 0):

After [some research](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9991). It is possible that still Hibernate has some bugs when filtering criteria with an attribute with `@Convert`. I have make several tests with different options with no success at all.

As a workaround, I have changed the `birthdate` attribute as a Long.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = LongCryptoConverter.class)
private Long birthdate;
```

Updating the setters and getters to convert the Timestamp to Long with `getTime()`

And creating a Long CryptoConverter with very simple methods for converting a Long to String and the opposite:

```
@Override
protected Long stringToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    try {
        return (dbData == null || dbData.isEmpty()) ? null : Long.parseLong(dbData);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        UsmoLogger.errorMessage(this.getClass().getName(), "Invalid long value in database.");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected String entityAttributeToString(Long attribute) {
    return attribute == null ? null : attribute.toString();
}
```

This is working as expected and the criteria filter now is working fine. Still I am not sure why the version with a Timestamp is not working fine.